# Preview a PDF/DOC/PPT/... on iOS4 page by page or allow at least accelerated scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, xamarin.ios

Currently I'm using UIDocumentInteractionController to preview my PDFs (and other mostly Office formats). I will change to QLPreviewController because I want to prevent the documents being opened outside my application.

However, my main problem remains: I would like to add some paging mechanism OR to allow at least accelerated scrolling within the documents (UIDocumentInteractionController always scrolls the same amount, no matter how "hard" you hit it).

Do I have to split my documents into separate pages and preview them all one by one? How would I achieve that?
Or is there a simpler, more elegant way?

I figured out the Quartz has some PDF support but I have to deal with various formats so that is not an option for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I still have no final answer to this issue. However, I managed to tweak QLPreviewController: dig down to find its scrollview, resize the preview panel, add a rotated (vertical) UISlider and make that act as a scrollbar. Then intercept the scrolling of the preview panel and update the UISlider so they stay in sync. Add some rotation code and done. But the main issue remains: QLPreviewController crashes on large (200MB+) files and there is no real paging, just fast scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing my own PDF viewer which previews page by page.